# EF6 with Oracle unable to Generate Database from Model in VS2015

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

In an newly created asp project 
in: `Generate Databases from Model...` after selecting the database connection, after click next,exception appears:
[image]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Running transformation: System.InvalidOperationException: The SSDL generated by the activity called 'CsdlToSsdlAndMslActivity' is not valid and has the following errors: 
No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGeneration.EdmExtension.CreateAndValidateStoreItemCollection(String ssdl, Version targetFrameworkVersion, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Boolean catchThrowNamingConflicts)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingFED2D73CEED00C99E8A0A14FA9AE33EAFFDF3CAAFEE9E04D21CC913F1C5C88D960592C81A433C11663E61FD5459CF679CFD9B7275B72CA8BFB8D753DBB9FDDE3.GeneratedTextTransformation.get_Store() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\GenerateTSQL.Utility.ttinclude:line 57
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingFED2D73CEED00C99E8A0A14FA9AE33EAFFDF3CAAFEE9E04D21CC913F1C5C88D960592C81A433C11663E61FD5459CF679CFD9B7275B72CA8BFB8D753DBB9FDDE3.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToSQL10.tt:line 84     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\GenerateTSQL.Utility.ttinclude   57
```

I think I have `the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config`

I have got Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess installed. by install Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework from nuget.

```
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="12.1.2400" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" version="12.1.2400" targetFramework="net452" />
```

And this is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
      connectionString="User Id=oracle_user;Password=oracle_user_password;Data Source=oracle"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am having the same problem but with SQLite.

Comment: i guess this is a bug in Oracle ODT or Virtual Studio,  I use Oracle Data modeler now.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem with this, did anyone figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change your model ddl generation from MS Sql to Mysql?
If no go to:
Model > Properties > Database Script Generation > DDL Generation Template > and change SSDLToSQL10.tt to SSDLToMySQL.tt .